# Django ModelForm dynamic field choices for a specific model

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to make the 'cost_name' field choices to be filtered based on the dynamic project_id.

models.py

```
class ProjectCost(models.Model):
    project_name = models.ForeignKey(ProjectName, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    cost_name = models.CharField('Cost Name', max_length=50)
    total_budget = models.DecimalField('Total Budget', max_digits=9,decimal_places=2)
```

forms.py

```
class CreateCostForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self,project_id,*args, **kwargs):

        super(CreateCostForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['cost_name'].queryset = ProjectCost.objects.filter(project_name_id=project_id)

    class meta:
        model = ProjectCost
```

When i hard-code the value of project_id like:

```
self.fields['project_name'].queryset = ProjectCost.objects.filter(project_name_id=4) or 
ProjectCost.objects.filter(project_name_id= 8),
```

i get the correct filtered options on the form.So how can i make **project_id** dynamic?

i tried:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    project_id = kwargs.pop('project_id', None)
    super(CreateCostForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['cost_name'].queryset = ProjectCost.objects.filter(project_name_id=project_id)
```

But this returns 'None' for the value of 'project_id'. Any idea on how to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are sub-classing from `CreateView`, then there is a method call [**`get_form_kwargs()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_form_kwargs) to send data from **View** to **Form**. Just override it like this:

```
class YourView(CreateView):
     ...
     def get_form_kwargs(self, *args, **kwargs):
         form_kwargs = super(YourView, self).get_form_kwargs(*args, **kwargs)
         form_kwargs['project_id'] = self.kwargs.get('project_id')  # assuming you send the project_id through url ie path('project/<int:project_id>/create/', YourView.as_view())
         return form_kwargs
```

In that way you will be get data in `project_id` in Form:

```
Class CreateCostForm(forms.ModelForm):
     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        project_id = kwargs.pop('project_id', None)
```

Comment: I am not sub-classing.I will try that and let you know.Thanks for the prompt response.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what i was looking for!